# How to impute the value in column by referencing a row in similar column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a data set where weight column has few values which is referencing to another cell in same column.

| ID | DN | Weight(Kilograms |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 83919 | 4282 | 2400 |
| . | . | . |
| . | . | . |
| 85678 | 4391 | 'See DN-4282 (ID#:83919)' |

i.e. impute 2400 in place of  'See DN-4282 (ID#:83919)'
I have written following code and getting output as series.

code:

```
df_shipment['Weight (Kilograms)'] = df_shipment['Weight (Kilograms)'].apply(lambda x:df_shipment['Weight (Kilograms)'].loc[df_shipment == int(x.split(' ')[2].split(':')[1][:-1]]) if 'See' in x else x )
output : series: 7935    2400
Name: Weight (Kilograms), dtype: object

Now how to extract value from series? Tried get() function but not working.
```

Comment: Please provide complete [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with example of the data and stack trace. The 'KeyError" does not seem to originate from the example data you provided.

Comment: Update your post wit the output of `df_shipment.head(10)` please.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question with an example dataset.

I imagine you have data like this:

```
                         value
ID                            
0                           10
1      See DN-4282 (ID#:83919)
83919                       30
```

and you want to replace the references with the actual values.

You can use `str.extract` to extract the reference as `map` it:

```
(df.value.str.extract('\(ID#:(\d+)\)')[0]
  .astype(float).astype('Int64')
  .map(df['value'])
  .where(lambda x: ~x.isna(), df['value'])
)
```

output:

```
ID
0        10
1        30
83919    30
```